# Javascript works and disappears quickly in Sitefinity

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sitefinity

I've been having an issue where JavaScript is not loading for our website built in Sitefinity. We have a custom .master page using the Zurb Foundation framework. At first I thought this was simply an ordering of the external scripts in the .

In breaking it down, I've stripped my page code to do a basic JavaScript output inline. When you click a button, it shows a text message. The script works for a split second then disappears. This is what I was having happen earlier. It's as though the script times out.

This is a basic of basic scripts to test. I don't understand why this is occurring. Something is conflicting with Sitefinity.

My code is below:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="Telerik.Sitefinity" Namespace="Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI.PublicControls" TagPrefix="sf" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="Telerik.Sitefinity" Namespace="Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI" TagPrefix="sf" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" TagPrefix="telerik" %>

<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head id="Head" runat="server">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Inside Page</title>

</head>  
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />

    <div id="ContentMainCPH">
        <asp:contentplaceholder id="ContentMainCPH" runat="server" />
    </div>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "This Works!";
        }
    </script>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Any thoughts about why I can't get Scripts to work in Sitefinity? I've been trying to resolve this for the entire week, and Sitefinity Support unfortunately is not of any help.

I appreciate your time and help if you can offer, thank you.

Maria

Comment: Hmm...it appears as though the <button> is causing the issue? It doesn't like buttons, but the script runs if <button> is replaced with <div>...what?

Comment: `onclick="myFunction(); return false"` The button submits the form, and so the page just refreshes. Adding `return false` prevents the default behavior of the button.

Comment: ...or add `type="button"` to the `button` element, and that'll disable the form submission behavior.

Comment: If I change the <button> to <asp:button>, it works. But is that really right?

Comment: Thanks @squint - I added the button type and it works great. This is just a small step to a bigger issue I have (reading my Foundation megamenu), but this is a start. I appreciate your help!